# Power consumption of vacuum tube

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, power

What is the power consumption of a vacuum diode? (or vacuum tube). I'm interested only in the "Anode supply voltage", this source typically has values of around $100\ \text{V}$ but I don't know how much power it consumes.
I think the power consumed is the electron current passing through the plate. Am I right?
[image]

Comment: I don't work with tubes but presumably they have datasheets like any other electronic component.

Comment: Well, yes, the anode voltage supply will need to be able to supply a power equal to V*I, where I is the current across the vacuum tube that it is driving. Current is current whether it is electrons in a wire, electrons in vacuum, or ions in a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power dissipation of vacuum tubes varies greatly depending on their size and what they are designed to do.  A typical vacuum *rectifier* (diode) will emit (as waste heat) anywhere from a watt to a hundred watts in the process of passing anywhere from tens of milliamps across a hundred volts to hundreds of milliamps across 500 volts or more.

This heat comes from two sources: the heater filament and the losses involved in producing the *plate current*, which is what I presume you are interested in. The most common rectifier tubes are the 5Y3 and the 5U4, for which data sheets are readily available online. The data sheets will chart out for you the power consumption of the filament and the *plate dissipation*.